# Should ViewModel class contain Android elements?

Tags: android, mvvm

Moving from MVP to MVVM and trying to learn from tutorials on web.

Some of the tutorials state that ViewModel classes should not have any reference to Activity or View(android.view.View) classes.

But in some of the tutorials i've seen Views are used in ViewModel class and Activities to start other Activities using ViewModel.
[For example:](https://www.journaldev.com/20292/android-mvvm-design-pattern)

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;

import com.journaldev.androidmvvmbasics.interfaces.LoginResultCallback;
import com.journaldev.androidmvvmbasics.model.User;

public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private User user;
    private LoginResultCallback mDataListener;

    LoginViewModel(@NonNull final LoginResultCallback loginDataListener) {
        mDataListener = loginDataListener;
        user = new User("", "");
    }


    public TextWatcher getEmailTextWatcher() {
        return new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                user.setEmail(editable.toString());
            }
        };
    }

    public TextWatcher getPasswordTextWatcher() {
        return new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                user.setPassword(editable.toString());
            }
        };
    }


    public void onLoginClicked(@NonNull final View view) {
        checkDataValidity();
    }

    private void checkDataValidity() {
        if (user.isInputDataValid())
            mDataListener.onSuccess("Login was successful");
        else {
            mDataListener.onError("Email or Password not valid");
        }
    }
}
```

[Another one](https://labs.ribot.co.uk/approaching-android-with-mvvm-8ceec02d5442) with `View.OnClickListener`

```
public class PostViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    private Context context;
    private Post post;
    private Boolean isUserPosts;

    public PostViewModel(Context context, Post post, boolean isUserPosts) {
        this.context = context;
        this.post = post;
        this.isUserPosts = isUserPosts;
    }

    public String getPostScore() {
        return String.valueOf(post.score) + context.getString(R.string.story_points);
    }

    public String getPostTitle() {
        return post.title;
    }

    public Spannable getPostAuthor() {
        String author = context.getString(R.string.text_post_author, post.by);
        SpannableString content = new SpannableString(author);
        int index = author.indexOf(post.by);
        if (!isUserPosts) content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), index, post.by.length() + index, 0);
        return content;
    }

    public int getCommentsVisibility() {
        return  post.postType == Post.PostType.STORY && post.kids == null ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE;
    }

    public View.OnClickListener onClickPost() {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Post.PostType postType = post.postType;
                if (postType == Post.PostType.JOB || postType == Post.PostType.STORY) {
                    launchStoryActivity();
                } else if (postType == Post.PostType.ASK) {
                    launchCommentsActivity();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public View.OnClickListener onClickAuthor() {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                context.startActivity(UserActivity.getStartIntent(context, post.by));
            }
        };
    }

    public View.OnClickListener onClickComments() {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchCommentsActivity();
            }
        };
    }

    private void launchStoryActivity() {
        context.startActivity(ViewStoryActivity.getStartIntent(context, post));
    }

    private void launchCommentsActivity() {
        context.startActivity(CommentsActivity.getStartIntent(context, post));
    }
}
```

[Another one](https://medium.com/tech-travelstart/android-data-binding-mvvm-4888eb73a25d) with Activity Reference

```
public class UserProfileViewModel {

    /* ------------------------------ Constructor */

    private Activity activity;

    /* ------------------------------ Constructor */

    UserProfileViewModel(@NonNull Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    /* ------------------------------ Main method */

    /**
     * On profile image clicked
     *
     * @param userName name of user
     */
    public void onProfileImageClicked(@NonNull String userName) {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("USERNAME", userName);
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, UserDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }

     /**
     * @param editable         editable
     * @param userProfileModel the model of user profile
     */
    public void userNameTextChange(@NonNull Editable editable,
                                   @NonNull UserProfileModel userProfileModel) {

        userProfileModel.setUserName(editable.toString());
        Log.e("ViewModel", userProfileModel.getUserName());
    }
}
```

1. Is it okay for ViewModel class to contain Android and View classes,
   isn't this bad for unit testing?
2. Which class should a custom view model class extend? `ViewModel` or
       `BaseObservable/Observable`?
3. Is there any tutorial link that shows simple usage of MVVM and with
   only focus on architecture without any Dagger2, LiveData, or RxJava
   extensions? I'm only looking for MVVM tutorials for now.

Comment: THe latest example you added is a very bad approach. **1.** `UserProfileViewModel` doesn't extend `ViewModel` and therefore defeats the purpose of that class. **2.** Keeping activity reference is bad because activity will get destroyed and that class is keeping it being garbage collected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel):

> Caution: A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context.

This is because a `ViewModel` survives configuration changes. Let's say you have an activity and you rotate the device. The activity is killed and a new instance is created. If you put views in the viewmodel, then the activity won't be garbage collected because the views hold the reference to the previous activity. Also, the views themselves will be recreated but you're keeping old views in the viewmodel. Basically don't put any views, context, activity in the viewmodel.

Here's a sample from google: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower/

Comment: Isn't ViewModel allowed to keep reference to ApplicationContext? Are these samples wrong? And which class should it extend? I guess it should be ViewModel from android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel, right? And is it necessary to rxjava2 if you use LiveData? Sample repo has rxjava2 too.

Comment: If you need `ApplicationContext`, you should extend `AndroidViewModel`; otherwise extend `ViewModel`. But don't pass context reference to the viewmodel. Rxjava2 is not mandatory if you use `LiveData`. I used rxjava for easier networking and lifecycle management. In simple terms LiveData just offers you the ability to observe a value and based on the changes you can update your UI.

Comment: The more tutorials and articles i watched i got more confused. Half of the people implement MVVM does not know how it supposed to be. How do you unit test samples in my question?

Comment: It varies from use cases to use case. But I'd recommend you to take a look at this [example from google's mvvm sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/test/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksViewModelTest.java). This is a Test class for a ViewModel

Comment: Most of the tutorials and articles add views/context in the viewmodel for convenience but that will later bite the dev. I'd suggest you to follow official documentation and google's samples from github

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate it. I'm looking into To-do app with MVVM but it's bit complex, i was actually looking like simple tutorials like i posted but half of them are wrong. I'm also watching yt videos but they got me confused further. It would be nice to have a tutorial with increasing complexity like changing a simple view's property to building a complete app like to-do app. I'm moving from sqlite to room and mvp to mvvm with live data, and planning to learn rxjava too. But i don't want mixed tutorials without mastering each one individually.

Comment: Check out my repo. Clone it and run it. It's a pretty small and simple app without too much going on

Comment: Hi, I have a question, I'd like to show messages using internationalization but I need the context for that (context.getString()). Should I return an enum(for example) to the activity and use a kind of `when` for choosing the message?. May someone give me a better solution?. Thanks.

Comment: @jmarkstar Your app should find the correct translations based on the locale of the device. But if you still want to pass xml-defined strings, then pass the id from the viewmodel. And use that id in the fragment/activity to do `getstring(id)`. Also, annotate the field that will take in the id: `data class Data(@StringRes val message: Int)` something like this. Doesn't have to be in a data class. You can annotate function parameters too

Comment: have a look at my question too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58536773/is-it-ok-to-use-sharedprefrence-with-coroutine-kotlin